# What are the characteristic of Asus Xtion Pro?

Tags: peripherals

What are the hardware characteristic of Asus Xtion Pro (a new peripheral for PC)? And which are the differences between Asus Xtion Pro and Microsoft Kinect?

Answer (score 0):

> WAVI Xtion is developed in collaboration with Prime Sense technology which is responsible for Kinect chamber in xbox 360 and the new device also consists of two devices: one to detect the movement and another to communicate wirelessly streaming data of relative moves.
>
> The company has said that it is compatible with PCs and TVs as it communicates via HDMI port which acts as Wireless data transfer, with this device you can enjoy high quality images and high-definition games on a range of up to 25 meters." [Source](http://discobytes.com/asus-introduced-their-kinect-killer-as-wavi-xtion/)

Differences?

- should be cheaper
- has support for PC
- wireless capabilities